# about the error of sample_n() "sizemust be less or equal than 2 (size of data), setreplace` = TRUE to use sampling with replacement"

Tags: r, dplyr

When I tried

```
  %>%group_by(id)%>%nest() %>%
     sample_n(10,replace = F)%>%unnest()
```

This sometimes works, but occasionally, it gives a message "size`must be less or equal than 2 (size of data), set`replace` = TRUE to use sampling with replacement".

Why??

Comment: You are `nest`ing, so each 'id' have a single row now with `data` column created as a `list` of tbl_dfs.  Pleasee show a reproducible example

Comment: You have fewer than 10 unique values in `id`.

Comment: No.
It worked before in the same dataset. 
I found a similar post, but I do not know how to fix.https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/1438

Answer (score 0):

This most commonly happens because you have fewer than *n* rows in some groups (in this case the error message is telling you that some group has only 2 rows).

The workaround is to use the [new function](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/slice.html) slice_sample(), which is meant to supersede sample_n() and sample_prop() anyway.

`slice_sample(n=10, replace = F)` does the same thing that your code does, except that if a group has only 2 rows it returns 2 rows for that group, instead of failing with an error.